# Spark Dataframe Vs Glue Dynamic Frame performance while writting

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I want to use glue glue_context.getSink operator to update metadata such as addition of partitions.
The initial data is spark dataframe is 40 gb and writing to s3 parquet file. Then running a crawler to update partitions.

Now I am trying to convert into dynamic frame and writing using below function. Its taking more time.

Questions: What happens when spark data frame is converted to dynamic freame? Is it a very costly operation?

```
sink = glue_context.getSink(
            connection_type="s3",
            path=output_s3_path,
            enableUpdateCatalog=True,
            updateBehavior="UPDATE_IN_DATABASE",
            partitionKeys=[partition_key],
```